# What is the meaning of Ttl in nload output?

Tags: centos7

Whats the meaning of `Ttl` in nload output? Whats the period of calculation?

```
#  Curr: 151.28 MBit/s
#  Avg: 161.08 MBit/s
#  Min: 144.97 MBit/s
#  Max: 192.01 MBit/s
#  Ttl: 126055.90 GByte
```

Answer (score 4):

It represents the total bytes received or sent via this interface as it can be seen from the output of `ifconfig ifname`.

It is just converted to Gbytes or Mbytes instead of showing it in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation the tool , the Ttl is refer for the Total amount of data transferred since the restart of the machine.